# R: remove "NO"s horizontally from data.frame

Tags: r

I've a data frame with 253 columns, and more than 10,000 rows.

Problem: I just need to keep the cells(not the entire rows) with the columns names, and remove the "NOs" from the row, based on the SKU column (using this as an ID).

Is there an easier way to remove horizontally all the "NOs", taking SKU column as an ID?

My Input:

```
SKU             Tv y Video    Cómputo    Tecnología Electrohogar     Decohogar  Deportes
2003091090002P  Tv y Video      NO       Tecnología      NO             NO      Deportes
2.00E+12        Tv y Video      NO       Tecnología      NO           NO        Deportes
2003120060006P  Tv y Video      NO       Tecnología      NO           NO        Deportes
2003120060006P  NO              NO            NO         NO           NO         NO
2.00E+12        NO              NO            NO         NO           NO         NO
2004121460000P  NO            Cómputo     Tecnología     NO          Decohogar          NO
2.00E+12        NO            Cómputo     Tecnología     NO          Decohogar          NO
2004121440002P  NO            Cómputo     Tecnología     NO          Decohogar          NO
2.00E+12        NO            Cómputo     Tecnología     NO          Decohogar          NO
```

My desiered output:

As you see in the "Deportes" colum, i have data from "Deportes" and "Decohogar". I don't mind combining this two, because i have the real data in each row.

```
SKU             Tv y Video  Cómputo     Deportes
2003091090002P  Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2.00E+12        Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2003120060006P  Tv y Video  Tecnología  Deportes
2004121460000P  Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2.00E+12        Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2004121440002P  Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
2.00E+12        Cómputo     Tecnología  Decohogar
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
structure(list(SKU = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
6L, 3L), .Label = c("2.00309E+12", "2.00312E+12", "2.00412E+12", 
"2003091090002P", "2003120060006P", "2004121440002P", "2004121460000P"
), class = "factor"), Tv.y.Video = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("NO", "Tv y Video"), class = "factor"), 
    Cómputo = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Cómputo", 
    "NO"), class = "factor"), Tecnología = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NO", "Tecnología"
    ), class = "factor"), Electrohogar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NO", class = "factor"), 
    Decohogar = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Decohogar", "NO"), class = "factor"), Deportes = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Deportes", "NO"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("SKU", "Tv.y.Video", "Cómputo", 
"Tecnología", "Electrohogar", "Decohogar", "Deportes"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: You could specify the 'NOs', 'blanks' etc with `na.strings=` in `read.csv/read.table` while reading and then remove the `NA` using `is.na()`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two questions here - one is a data processing question (how to clean all those `NO` values into `NA'), and a subsetting question (how to only select rows that have no missing values.

Here's a reproducible example that uses the `mutate_each` columnwise function in `dplyr` to clean all your columns:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

#has NAs
summary(flights)

munge_me <- function(x) {ifelse(is.na(x), -1, x)}

flights_prepped <- flights %>%
  mutate_each(
    funs(munge_me)    
  )

#NAs are gone, and you have -1 instead
summary(flights_prepped)
```

Once you have your values correctly tagged NA, you can use `complete.cases()` to subset your data frame to *only* the rows that have no NA.

```
nrow(flights)
nrow(flights[complete.cases(flights), ])
```

Comment: it wont work cause i have some "NOs" in every row. As you see from my data example, allways i'll have 3 columns the right data, but with "Nos" in the middle, start or end. I just need to remove those horizontally, taking in consideration the SKU column.

Comment: can you explain more by 'remove those horizontally?' maybe put the desired output into the question?

Comment: i've updated my input. Thank you for your help. Hope is more clear now.